# How to fix 'SyntaxError: Unexpected token :'

Tags: javascript, nearley

I'm trying to get nearley working, but I end up receiving 'SyntaxError: Unexpected token :'.

The issue is shown when I run `nearley-test -i "help" command.js`, and I'm not entirely sure what the cause of it is. As I'm not too familiar with javascript and this is some old legacy code it may be that some things have stopped working in later versions of javascript/node?

Error:

```sh
➜  src git:(master) nearley-test -i "help" command.js
function id(d: any[]): any { return d[0]; }
             ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
    at new Script (vm.js:80:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:274:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:326:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:664:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
```

Code:

```
// Generated automatically by nearley, version 2.19.0
// http://github.com/Hardmath123/nearley
// Bypasses TS6133. Allow declared but unused functions.
// @ts-ignore
function id(d: any[]): any { return d[0]; }
declare var tip: any;
declare var withdraw: any;
declare var deposit: any;
declare var balance: any;
declare var help: any;
declare var eth: any;
declare var address: any;
declare var ens: any;
declare var username: any;
declare var number: any;
declare var any: any;
declare var space: any;

import { CommandType } from './parser'
import * as moo from 'moo'

const lexer = moo.compile({
  space: / +/,
  ens: /[0-9a-zA-Z-]+\.eth/,
  address: /0x[0-9a-fA-F]{40}/,
  username: /@[0-9a-zA-Z_]{1,15}/,
  number: /(?:[1-9][0-9]*|0)(?:\.[0-9]+)?/,
  eth: /[eE]ther|ETH|[eE]th/,
  tip: /[tT]ip/,
  withdraw: /[wW]ithdraw/,
  deposit: /[dD]eposit/,
  balance: /[bB]alance/,
  help: /[hH]elp/,
  any: /.+/
})

interface NearleyToken {  value: any;
  [key: string]: any;
};

interface NearleyLexer {
  reset: (chunk: string, info: any) => void;
  next: () => NearleyToken | undefined;
  save: () => any;
  formatError: (token: NearleyToken) => string;
  has: (tokenType: string) => boolean;
};

interface NearleyRule {
  name: string;
  symbols: NearleySymbol[];
  postprocess?: (d: any[], loc?: number, reject?: {}) => any;
};

type NearleySymbol = string | { literal: any } | { test: (token: any) => boolean };

interface Grammar {
  Lexer: NearleyLexer | undefined;
  ParserRules: NearleyRule[];
  ParserStart: string;
};

const grammar: Grammar = {
  Lexer: lexer,
  ParserRules: [
    {"name": "Main", "symbols": ["AnyCommand", "_"], "postprocess": d => d[0]},
    {"name": "Main", "symbols": ["AnyCommand", "__", "Any"], "postprocess": d => d[0]},
    {"name": "AnyCommand", "symbols": ["TipCommand"], "postprocess": id},
    {"name": "AnyCommand", "symbols": ["WithdrawCommand"], "postprocess": id},
    {"name": "AnyCommand", "symbols": ["BalanceCommand"], "postprocess": id},
    {"name": "AnyCommand", "symbols": ["DepositCommand"], "postprocess": id},
    {"name": "AnyCommand", "symbols": ["HelpCommand"], "postprocess": id},
    {"name": "TipCommand", "symbols": ["_", (lexer.has("tip") ? {type: "tip"} : tip), "__", "Username"], "postprocess": d => ({ type: CommandType.TIP, username: d[3] })},
    {"name": "TipCommand", "symbols": ["TipCommand", "_", "Amount"], "postprocess": d => Object.assign(d[0], d[2])},
    {"name": "WithdrawCommand", "symbols": ["_", (lexer.has("withdraw") ? {type: "withdraw"} : withdraw), "__", "Amount", "__", "AddressOrENS"], "postprocess": d => Object.assign({ type: CommandType.WITHDRAW, address: d[5] }, d[3])},
    {"name": "DepositCommand", "symbols": ["_", (lexer.has("deposit") ? {type: "deposit"} : deposit)], "postprocess": d => ({ type: CommandType.DEPOSIT })},
    {"name": "BalanceCommand", "symbols": ["_", (lexer.has("balance") ? {type: "balance"} : balance)], "postprocess": d => ({ type: CommandType.BALANCE })},
    {"name": "HelpCommand", "symbols": ["_", (lexer.has("help") ? {type: "help"} : help)], "postprocess": d => ({ type: CommandType.HELP })},
    {"name": "Amount", "symbols": ["Number", "_", "Symbol"], "postprocess": d => ({ amount: d[0], symbol: d[2] })},
    {"name": "Symbol", "symbols": [(lexer.has("eth") ? {type: "eth"} : eth)], "postprocess": d => 'ETH'},
    {"name": "AddressOrENS", "symbols": ["Address"], "postprocess": id},
    {"name": "AddressOrENS", "symbols": ["ENS"], "postprocess": id},
    {"name": "Address", "symbols": [(lexer.has("address") ? {type: "address"} : address)], "postprocess": d => d[0].value},
    {"name": "ENS", "symbols": [(lexer.has("ens") ? {type: "ens"} : ens)], "postprocess": d => d[0].value},
    {"name": "Username", "symbols": [(lexer.has("username") ? {type: "username"} : username)], "postprocess": d => d[0].value.slice(1)},
    {"name": "Number", "symbols": [(lexer.has("number") ? {type: "number"} : number)], "postprocess": d => parseFloat(d[0].value)},
    {"name": "Any", "symbols": [(lexer.has("any") ? {type: "any"} : any)], "postprocess": d => d[0].value},
    {"name": "_$ebnf$1", "symbols": [(lexer.has("space") ? {type: "space"} : space)], "postprocess": id},
    {"name": "_$ebnf$1", "symbols": [], "postprocess": () => null},
    {"name": "_", "symbols": ["_$ebnf$1"], "postprocess": d => null},
    {"name": "__", "symbols": [(lexer.has("space") ? {type: "space"} : space)], "postprocess": d => null}
  ],
  ParserStart: "Main",
};

export default grammar;
```

CommandType as referenced is:

```
export enum CommandType {
  TIP = 'tip',
  WITHDRAW = 'withdraw',
  DEPOSIT = 'deposit',
  BALANCE = 'balance',
  HELP = 'help'
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The code in "generated by nearley" snippet is Typescript; *not* JavaScript. How do you generate it in the first place?

Comment: ah yes so the nearly code can be found here: https://github.com/Cygnusfear/tipether/blob/master/src/command.ne

It is then generated by using: nearleyc command.ne -o command.ts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so, you generate Typescript: -o command.**ts**, but then your utility expects JavaScript. Generate JavaScript instead: `nearleyc command.ne -o command.js`